# Simple way to remove EXIF data from a JPEG with .NET

Tags: .net, exif

How can I remove all EXIF data from a JPEG image?

I found lots of examples on how to read and edit the EXIF data with various libraries, but all I would need is a simple example on how to remove it.

It is just for testing proposes, so even the ugliest and hackished approach would be helpful :)

I already tried searching for the EXIF start/end markers 0xFFE1 & 0xFFE2. The last one does not exist in my case.

Comment: because of this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001537/localreport-render-fails-with-images-from-nikon-coolpix-5600

Comment: Have you considered offering up some rep for this?  It looks like straightforward grunt-work.

Comment: Funny old world... I'm always paranoid that I'm going to accidentally remove the EXIF data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think reading in the file into a Bitmap object and writing out to a file again should do the trick.

I remember feeling frustrated while doing my "image rotation program" that it removed the EXIF data. But in this case, it's exactly what you want!

Answer (score 28):

I first wrote about this using WPF libs in my blog, but this sort of failed since Windows backend calls are a bit messed up.

My [final solution](http://techmikael.blogspot.com/2009/07/removing-exif-data-continued.html) is also much quicker which basically byte patches the jpeg in order to remove the exif. Fast and simple :)

**[EDIT: Blog post has more updated code]**

```
namespace ExifRemover
{
  public class JpegPatcher
  {
    public Stream PatchAwayExif(Stream inStream, Stream outStream)
    {
      byte[] jpegHeader = new byte[2];
      jpegHeader[0] = (byte) inStream.ReadByte();
      jpegHeader[1] = (byte) inStream.ReadByte();
      if (jpegHeader[0] == 0xff && jpegHeader[1] == 0xd8)
      {
        SkipExifSection(inStream);
      }

      outStream.Write(jpegHeader,0,2);

      int readCount;
      byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
      while ((readCount = inStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
        outStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, readCount);

      return outStream;
    }

    private void SkipExifSection(Stream inStream)
    {
      byte[] header = new byte[2];
      header[0] = (byte) inStream.ReadByte();
      header[1] = (byte) inStream.ReadByte();
      if (header[0] == 0xff && header[1] == 0xe1)
      {
        int exifLength = inStream.ReadByte();
        exifLength = exifLength << 8;
        exifLength |= inStream.ReadByte();

        for (int i = 0; i < exifLength - 2; i++)
        {
          inStream.ReadByte();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly while saving using Bitmap didn't quite work for me.

Comment: Mikael, this is a great Solution, but I am curious about something. In `SkipAppHeaderSection` (from your blog, not the code posted here), you're iterating over the bytes in pairs and always checking if the first is `0xff` and if the second is between `0xe0` and `0xef`. How does this indicate the beginning and end of a JPG header? Most curious as to why the first in the pair would always be `0xe0`.

Comment: Been a looong time, but I think I encountered images which had other headers before the exif one, thus I loop until I found the exif one with the correct signature of 0xff 0xe0

Answer (score 0):

what you should avoid is to decode and re-encode your images because this will hurt the quality. instead you should find a way to modify only the metadata. i haven't tried it but i think [InPlaceBitmapMetadataWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.inplacebitmapmetadatawriter.aspx) will do the trick.

Comment: You're right that decoding/re-encoding will hurt quality (to some extent). I think it's up to the poster to decide if it's worth the effort based upon what he needs.

Comment: i looked into it thx, but it`s way to complicated for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Been a long time since this question but ran into an issue with this recently.  These two functions will remove EXIF data from JPG's provided either as a filepath or byte[] array, without needing any third party packages.

```
internal static class ExifRemover
{
    internal static byte[] RemoveExifDataFromImage(string filePath)
    {
        using (var originalImage = Image.FromFile(filePath))
        {
            return Copy(originalImage);
        }
    }
    internal static byte[] RemoveExifDataFromImage(byte[] imageBytes)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
        using (var originalImage = Image.FromStream(ms))
        {
            return Copy(originalImage);
        }
    }
    private static byte[] Copy(Image originalImage)
    {
        using (var newImage = new Bitmap(originalImage.Width, originalImage.Height))
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            g.DrawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, originalImage.Width, originalImage.Height);
            var b = new Bitmap(newImage);
            var converter = new ImageConverter();
            return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(b, typeof(byte[]));
        }
    }
}
```

It works by copying the image to a new bitmap.  With the returned byte array, you can call `context.Response.BinaryWrite` to write the image to the response.

Answer (score -2):

It's too easy, use jhead.exe from here: http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/

Make a little batch file if you want e.g.:
`jhead.exe -purejpg *.jpg`

It will strip all metadata from all jpegs in the same folder.