# Easy way to clean metadata from an image?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, metadata, system.drawing

I'm working on a service for a company project that handles image processing, and one of the methods is supposed to clean the metadata from an image passed to it.

I *think* implementation I currently have works, but I'm not sure if it's affecting the quality of images or if there's a better way to handle this task. Could you let me know if you know of a better way to do this?

Here's the method in question:

```
public byte[] CleanMetadata(byte[] data)
{
    Image image;

    if (tryGetImageFromBytes(data, out image))
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image);

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

            graphics.DrawImage(image, new Point(0, 0));
        }

        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();

        return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));
    }

    return null;
}
```

And, for reference, the `tryGetImageFromBytes` method:

```
private bool tryGetImageFromBytes(byte[] data, out Image image)
{
    try
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        image = null;

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

To reiterate: is there a better way to remove metadata from an image that doesn't involve redrawing it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do this with [exiftool or ImageMagick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654281/how-to-remove-exif-data-without-recompressing-the-jpeg)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I'm not using UNIX.

Comment: exiftool works for any OS granted you have a way to run a perl script.

Comment: @EvanL There's a [stand-alone Windows executable version of exiftool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) that doesn't even require Perl

Comment: @squeamishossifrage or that ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **The .NET way**: You may want to try your hand at the [System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class - more precisely, its [`Metadata`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder.metadata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection. Quoting MSDN:

> Metadata - Gets or sets the metadata that will be associated with this
>   bitmap during encoding.

- **The 'Oops, I (not so accidentally) forgot something way**: Open the original bitmap file into a [`System.drawing.Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object. [Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it to a new `Bitmap` object. Write the clone's contents to a new file. Like this one-liner:

  ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\file.png").Clone()).Save(@"C:\file-nometa.png");
- **The direct file manipulation way** (only for JPEG): [Blog post about removing the EXIF area](http://techmikael.blogspot.com/2009/07/removing-exif-data-continued.html).

Comment: I'm using VS2012, and for some reason that namespace doesn't exist in the 4.5 framework. Any reason I might not be able to find it?

Comment: Never mind, found it. It's located in `PresentationCore.dll`.

Comment: That was quick - you found the assembly before I finished my edit. =)

Comment: Selecting this as the answer since you provided a few different solutions. I'm sure future viewers would appreciate some code, though :P

Comment: To tell the truth, I agree with you, @kehrk, and often do it; But I can't test the first option right now. Included an one-liner for the second.

Comment: @thang: Noticed the same thing. What does not work: `var image2 = image1.Clone() as Bitmap`. What does work: `var image2 = new Bitmap(image1)`. In the latter case, `image2` will really be encoded into an image that is really smaller than `image1` if there's metadata.

Comment: Also at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005463/simple-way-to-remove-exif-data-from-a-jpeg-with-net

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this, the source is here: [Removing Exif-Data for jpg file](http://www.techmikael.com/2009/07/removing-exif-data-continued.html?showComment=1475736540448#c7406044852816798056)

**Changing a bit the 1st function**

```
public Stream PatchAwayExif(Stream inStream)
{
  Stream outStream = new MemoryStream();
  byte[] jpegHeader = new byte[2];
  jpegHeader[0] = (byte)inStream.ReadByte();
  jpegHeader[1] = (byte)inStream.ReadByte();
  if (jpegHeader[0] == 0xff && jpegHeader[1] == 0xd8) //check if it's a jpeg          file
  {
     SkipAppHeaderSection(inStream);
  }
  outStream.WriteByte(0xff);
  outStream.WriteByte(0xd8);

  int readCount;
  byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
  while ((readCount = inStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
  outStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, readCount);

  return outStream;
}
```

**And the second function with no changes, as post**

```
    private void SkipAppHeaderSection(Stream inStream)
    {
        byte[] header = new byte[2];
        header[0] = (byte)inStream.ReadByte();
        header[1] = (byte)inStream.ReadByte();

        while (header[0] == 0xff && (header[1] >= 0xe0 && header[1] <= 0xef))
        {
            int exifLength = inStream.ReadByte();
            exifLength = exifLength << 8;
            exifLength |= inStream.ReadByte();

            for (int i = 0; i < exifLength - 2; i++)
            {
                inStream.ReadByte();
            }
            header[0] = (byte)inStream.ReadByte();
            header[1] = (byte)inStream.ReadByte();
        }
        inStream.Position -= 2; //skip back two bytes
    }
```

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252097/136285

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new bitmap will clear out all the exif data.

```
var newImage = new Bitmap(image);
```

If you want to remove only specific info:

```
private Image RemoveGpsExifInfo(Image image)
{
  foreach (var item in image.PropertyItems)
  {
    // GPS range is from 0x0000 to 0x001F. Full list here -> https://exiftool.org/TagNames/EXIF.html (click on GPS tags)
    if (item.Id <= 0x001F)
    {
      image.RemovePropertyItem(item.Id);
    }
  }

  return image;
}
```