# Is Image guaranteed to be disposed in this method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-leaks, idisposable

Given the code where `resizedImage` is of the type  `System.Drawing.Image`:

```
using (var resizedImage = Resizer.ResizeImage(bytes, requestedWidth))
{
    return PNGCompressor.LosslesslyCompressPNG(resizedImage);
}
```

And the method is defined as:

```
public static byte[] LosslesslyCompressPNG(Image image)
{
    var fileName = Guid.NewGuid();
    var inputFilePath = TempCompressionFolder + fileName + ".png";
    image.Save(inputFilePath, ImageFormat.Png);

    var outputFilePath = TempCompressionFolder + fileName + "_comp.png";

    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = PathToOptiPNGExe,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        Arguments = "\"" + inputFilePath + "\" -out \"" + outputFilePath + "\" -o2 -strip all"
    };
    using (var process = Process.Start(startInfo))
    {
        if (process == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not start " + PathToOptiPNGExe);
        }
        process.WaitForExit(Settings.Executables.WaitForExitMS);
        if (!process.HasExited)
        {
            process.Kill();
        }
    }

    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(outputFilePath);
    File.Delete(outputFilePath);
    File.Delete(inputFilePath);
    return bytes;
}
```

Will `resizedImage` always be disposed?  I'm wondering if this is a source of a memory leak or not due to the new process being started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) guarantee that `Dispose` will be called even in the case of an exception.

The fact that you are starting new process won't do anything with this instance because you are not using the instance with this new process only `string` parameter. Even if you were using this instance (through stream parameter or whatever), the `using` statement will take care of disposing and releasing the instance.

By the way, what I understand is that you are using optipng tool only to "strip" metadata. There is many other way of doing it without involving creating a file on disk and starting a new process. See [easy way to clean metadata from an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586699/easy-way-to-clean-metadata-from-an-image) for example

Comment: Great thanks for confirming.  The process strips out metadata, but is also losslessly compressing it.  I don't think this is necessary anymore as the Cloudflare layer takes care of that so will probably switch it out for your suggestion.