# Inserting ImageUniqueID into a JPEG's EXIF data without modifying the image using .NET

Tags: c#, exif, imagesharp

I have a requirement to insert a unique ID into image files without modifying the image content – ie it’s just the metadata that I want to modify. I’m starting with the JPEG files because there is an appropriate EXIF property available: *ImageUniqueID*.

I’m using C# with .NET Core 3.1 for this exercise with [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp). 
I can change the EXIF data with the ImageSharp using the following code (show simplified without existing record checks, etc):

```
using (var image = Image.Load(filename))
            {
            var imageUniqueIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToLower().Replace("-", "");
            image.Metadata.ExifProfile.SetValue(ExifTag.ImageUniqueID, imageUniqueIdentifier);

            var jpegEncoder = new JpegEncoder() { Quality = 100 };
            image.Save(filename, jpegEncoder);
            }
```

I did play with the Quality setting in the JpegEncoder, but was still getting either unacceptable quality degradation or file size increases.

Is there a way of just reading the meta data, altering it and then writing it back without affecting the image at all?

I also looked at [MetadataExtractor.NET](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet) but this doesn’t have a write facility and would happily look at other .NET Core methods or libraries.

Comment: Do you really need imagesharp or is it ok with WPF?

Comment: If you have 1000 dollars you could try this. It seems to do what you want: https://blog.groupdocs.com/2020/05/13/manage-exif-data-in-csharp-net-for-jpeg-png-tiff-webp-images/. Or one of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005463/simple-way-to-remove-exif-data-from-a-jpeg-with-net)

Comment: @SimonMourier I used ImageSharp because I thought it might do the job. I was processing files that were going onto the web and wanted to give them a unique embedded ID so that if the file name got changed for any reason, I could still track it down.

Comment: I was asking because there's a .NET only solution, I have not tested in asp.net but it may work (not using any desktop UI).

Comment: I'm happy with a .NET solution, but is it confined to *Windows Presentation Foundation*?

Answer (score 7):

After some research I've found that there is [ExifLibrary](https://github.com/oozcitak/exiflibrary) which allow you to modify only image metadata.
[Documentation](http://oozcitak.github.io/exiflibrary/articles/SaveFile.html) (examples included)

Example how to add unique image id for jpg file:

```
var file = ImageFile.FromFile("path_to_jpg_file");
var imageUniqueIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToLower().Replace("-", "");
file.Properties.Set(ExifLibrary.ExifTag.ImageUniqueID, imageUniqueIdentifier);

file.Save("path_to_jpg_file");
```

Nuget package: ExifLibNet.

Comment: I took a look at this library and at first blush, it seems to do what I want. A test using _Beyond Compare_ between an original test image and the modified image showed that the _Image unique ID_ was correctly inserted. However, a few other properties were changed, though I'm still trying to work out if they are significant or matter. They were _GPS offset (8825), Interoperability offset (A005), Scene Type (A301) and JIF offset (0201)_.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code that just needs .NET with PresentationCore and WindowsBase. The underlying technology that WPF uses is WIC ([Windows Imaging Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-about-windows-imaging-codec)). WIC has full support for [image metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-about-metadata).

EXIF's *ImageUniqueID* is handled specifically as a Windows Property named [System.Image.ImageID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-photoprop-system-image-imageid)

Some other properties such as System.Photo.CameraModel can be seen directly in Windows Explorer detailed views if you add the corresponding column "Camera Model", but not System.Image.ImageID, AFAIK.

```
// needs PresentationCore & WindowsBase references
var frame = BitmapDecoder.Create(new Uri("test1.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.None).Frames[0];

// create encoder, add frame, we need to copy since we want to update metadata
var encoder = BitmapEncoder.Create(frame.Decoder.CodecInfo.ContainerFormat);
var copy = BitmapFrame.Create(frame);

// get frame metadata
var metaData = (BitmapMetadata)copy.Metadata;

// show existing System.Image.ImageID (if any)
Console.WriteLine("ImageUniqueID: " + metaData.GetQuery("System.Image.ImageID"));

// for some reason, we can't use "System.Image.ImageID" to set the meta data
// so use the "Metadata Query Language"
metaData.SetQuery("/app1/ifd/exif/{ushort=42016}", "My Super ID");

// write file back
encoder.Frames.Add(copy);
using (var stream = File.OpenWrite("test1copy.jpg"))
{
    encoder.Save(stream);
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling to find a means of referencing WIC in a .NET Core 5 console project (I'm just using a console project for experiment). I tried [this library](https://github.com/sbaeumlisberger/WIC-DotNet) as expedite things but it quickly got a bit too C++ for me with integer pointers, etc - I haven't done C++ for decades. 
My Visual Studio installation includes *.NET desktop development* but not C++ desktop development. I don't really want to install the latter if I can help it.

Comment: @CrispinH - You don't have to use WIC itself. If you're using a .NET Core Console app, it's the same code, just make sure you have this in your csproj: `<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>DisableWinExeOutputInference>true</DisableWinExeOutputInference><UseWPF>true</UseWPF>`

Comment: That's now worked but some parameters have changed compared to the original: *Exif offset (8769), GPS offset (8825), Interoperability offset (A005), JIF offset (0201)* and *Unknown (E1AD)* added. I'm guessing this last probably won't matter. As for the others, I will try to give some time to reading the original values for these and may be setting them back programmatically.